# Thermometer no longer working

Tags: gpio, ds18b20, 1-wire

I am running the below lines to try to load my two therms.

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio
sudo modprobe w1-therm
ls /sys/bus/w1/devices
```

All I am getting is 00- instead of 28-

I have checked wiring, works fine.  It has been working for months but had to replace SD card due to failure.

I've also added to `/boot/config.txt` - `dtoverlay=w1-gpio`

Power is hooked to 3.3, data is to GPIO 4.

Everything is up to date.

Comment: You don't need the modprobes any more, just put the dtoverlay line in `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.  If that doesn't work add the output of `uname -a` to your question.

Comment: Have you changed the /boot/cmdline.txt with:

bcm2708.w1_gpio_pin=X
?